# Slim php framework showing blank page for hello world example

Tags: php, rest, restful-url, slim

oh boy... Hey guys hope all is well. 
I'm an iphone/ipad programmer, wanting to create a webservice with a few methods that I could then send json requests to the webservice and make it all jolly.

I'm currently trying to create a web service. This is my host: justhost.com. I understand I wont be able to setup any sort of .net framework since its all linux. I then was told i could however setup a web service with slim or epiphany. Both of which I've been told shouldn't take long at all to setup. 5 mins max? I have however spent the last 2 days trying to make things work with little success.

I stuck with Slim since, in my opinion, it has an easier setup compared with epiphany. I now am testing an hello world example so that I am then able to write something like this in my webpage....

*testing.mysite.com/hello/pk*

but I'm just getting blank pages. im assuming that my .htaccess file must be correct for any url i write in the address bar with a prefix of my site to not throw a incorrect error page.

This is what my folder directory looks like atm:

[image]

And i've inserted the .htaccess file that was provided by the Slim framework.

What else do i need to do to make this work. what am i missing. I hope someone can help me with this.

**UPDATE 1**

This is the error im receiving.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home1/dholnot1/public_html/testing/index.php on line 8 I then removed the semi colon at the end of the require statement and that changed the error to this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home1/dholnot1/public_html/testing/index.php on line 5

**UPDATE 2**

This is my code:

```
<?php

    require 'Slim/Slim.php';

    $app = new \Slim\Slim();

    //GET route
    $app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
        echo "Hello, $name";
    });

    //POST route
    $app->post('/person', function () {
        //Create new Person
    });

    //PUT route
    $app->put('/person/:id', function ($id) {
        //Update Person identified by $id
    });

    //DELETE route
    $app->delete('/person/:id', function ($id) {
        //Delete Person identified by $id
    });     


    $app->run();
?>
```

**UPDATE 3**

I have upgraded php configuration to PHP Version 5.3.18
which means anonymous functions will work now.

this is the new error im getting:
 Fatal error: Class 'Slim\Log' not found in /home1/dholnot1/public_html/testing/Slim/Slim.php on line 242

i've checked in the slim.php file at line 242 and it reads this:

> 'log.level' => \Slim\Log::DEBUG,

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on the server? Do you have access to erro log? Can you switch on error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Yes php is definitely installed. And yes i have access to the php.ini file... So Slim can show error reports... hmm interesting.. ill just see which value my the variable is showing in my php.ini file one moment..

Comment: so i've copied the php.ini file into my add on domain... and set display_errors to on and i notice that error_reporting is already set to E_ALL the hello world example still shows a blank page

Comment: You should do some debugging. Put an `echo 'test';` before your `require` statement to see if that gets printed. Then after the `require`, then after the next line and so on. You could also create a `test.php` with `phpinfo()` in it. It will show you all the PHP settings. That way you can make sure `error_reporting` is on.

Comment: fair enough i know exactly what debugging steps you're talking about. ill go ahead and do those now

Comment: This is the error im receiving..

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home1/dholnot1/public_html/testing/index.php on line 8

I then removed the semi colon at the end of the require statement and that changed the error to this:

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home1/dholnot1/public_html/testing/index.php on line 5

Comment: Please provide your code, otherwise it's impossible to help. Btw: which version of PHP do you use? [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) are available in >=PHP 5.3.

Comment: sure i will paste the code now

Comment: and im using PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: please check the post. i have not included update 2 and 3.

Comment: Okay, perfect. You should register the autoloader of Slim, to it can handle it's dependecies on it's own. Just include the following line after the `require`: `\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();`

Comment: WOW Odi..... it WORKS!!! all is working well!

the only thing is that just today about 12 hours ago... i contacted an indian company to create a RESTful api for me... to integrate with amazon webservices... so i will see what php frameworks they've used to make it all work. i will found out tomorrow how theyve done it all.

Odi.. could you please add it in your post so i can select your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below:

```php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

//GET route
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});

...


$app->run();
```

- Slim uses [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php), so you must use `$app = new \Slim\Slim()`
- Use the autoloader to let Slim handle it's internal dependencies

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response. was caught up in the christmas holidays. So Odi, I appreciate the response. ATM I'm just getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home1/dholnot1/public_html/testing/index.php on line 5
 ... what can I do to make all this work? just a simple test is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you can update your question with the actual code your using. It's impossible to tell what's wrong without knowing the code. Did you replace the 2nd line with my solution?

Comment: hey odi... could you update your post to include the autoloader code.. so i can correct this post as my answer

Comment: So the indian company i hired said this to me...
"When giving URL redirection POST data it is not carried forward with it" how can i point them in the right direction? i believe they are just using CORE PHP.. i've asked them to be able to do this... webserviceurl.com/var/var/var/var/add/agent